# I have finished or I finished with simple present tense in one sentence

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I'd like to know if it is possible to use present perfect or past simple in the following sentence:

> After I finish my work, I leave my workplace and go home.

Are either of these acceptable?

> After I ***have finished*** my work, I leave my workplace and go home
>
> After I ***finished*** my work, I leave my workplace and go home

Comment: If you keep "leave my workplace" and "go home" (both present tense) then it's inappropriate to change "finish" to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Several tenses are possible here. Here are a few, ordered from simple and frequent to cumbersome and rare:

1. > After I finish my work, I leave my workplace.
2. > After finishing my work, I leave my workplace.
3. > After I've finished my work, I leave my workplace.
4. > After having finished my work, I leave my workplace.

It's "leave" in present tense that demands that the previous verb, "finish", have some connection to the present, whether it be in simple present or a gerund. But the general structure of the sentence "After X, then Y" guarantees that they more or less all mean the same thing.